# Do I need an internet connection to play Call of Duty: World At War Zombies on PC?

Tags: call-of-duty-world-at-war, cod-world-at-war-zombies

I'm interested in buying Call of Duty: World at War on Steam. I bought Black Ops II in hopes of playing the zombies. However I'm at my lake house where there is no internet and BO2 zombies requires you to hook up to their database for the highscores.

So the question is: Do I need internet to play WaW zombies on the PC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do **not** need Internet to play WAW Zombies. However, you **do** need Internet to play Multiplayer in general (unless you can find a split-screen mod). When I say Multiplayer, I mean the Multiplayer game mode and WAW Zombies with other people online.

**Edit:** I have first-hand proof that you do not need an Internet connection to play WAW Zombies. When I play WAW Zombies, I don't need Internet **unless** I am playing on Multiplayer Modes (zombies, team deathwatch, campaign co-op, etc..).

Comment: There seems to be 2 different answers. Could you provide some evidence? From a website or something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing with no internet connection, I *believe* the only zombies you will able to play is the first map: "Nacht Der Untoten". This is only unlocked once you complete the main campaign.

If you are able to download a few of the map packs, you will likely need an update as well, but once you do you should be able to play them all off line.

**Note:** This is for console - I have no experience for PC

Comment: There seems to be 2 different answers. Could you provide some evidence? From a website or something.

Comment: Only from personal experience. I have all the map packs, which I can play all offline. However, If I remove all my updates on the game, and attempt to play it offline, I will only be able to play "Nach Der Untoten", and only through the campaign menu. Once you update the game however, it will be accessible, along with any other downloaded maps, form a separate "Nazi Zombies" menu option.

Answer (score -3):

Of course you can play WAW Zombies, as long as you have required map packs downloaded. However, if you want to play with other people **online**, then you must have a proper internet connection. It's just like any other game you've downloaded. If offline, you can only play things you have downloaded. If online, you can do that and connect to other players and servers.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that hasn't already been mentioned, I'm afraid.